# People API not retrieving all contacts

Tags: java, google-api, httprequest, google-people-api, import-contacts

I'm using the Google People API to retrieve my contacts, but I'm not able to retrieve all of them.
I've checked my API key and quotas, and everything seems to be in order. I've also verified that the contacts I'm trying to retrieve are not hidden.

Here's the a part of the code I'm using to make the API request:

```
URI uri = URI.create("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=2000&personFields=names");
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = 
  HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(uri)
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
    .GET()
    .build();
```

The API is only returning 1000, even though I have 2700 contacts stored in my account. I actually would like to have a solution not to be limited in only 2000 or less, i want to be able to get all my contacts so that i can save them in my database.
I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Is that not the [max page size](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.page_size)?

Comment: Yes, but, is it possible to get the next 1700 contacts ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: is there a next page token returned?

Comment: Can you guide me on how to retrieve the rest of my contacts? What should I add to the API request to achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no next page returned.

Comment: You can get the next page token inside the response body. You will get something like [this](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#response-body). Have you tried to add a logger.log or something similar from the response?